# SUMIFS returns 0 using dynamic criteria, with criteria range and sum range on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

Anyone,

I've chatted with and called excel customer service with no luck.  I used the formula builder (please see attached screenshot) to make sure each element of the formula is correct and returns the value for the criteria I'm trying to reference.

Everything is accurate, but it returns a value of 0.  When I do the same thing in the actual sheet the data is stored in (and click a criteria cell within the criteria range) it returns the accurate value?!  I'm not sure why it won't work on the other sheet.  The values I am using to select are dynamic and change with a drop down.  I have another, advanced, workbook (I did not create) that does the same thing and completes an even more complicated formula, but actually works so I'm not sure why this is returning a 0 value.

Photos and code/syntax: [Dynamic Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOyuV.png), [Example 2 of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIwT.png), [Example 1 of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CMar.png), [Formula Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsIIk.png), [CountIFs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drjW2.png), [Advanced Spreadsheet working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWyEy.png), [VLOOKUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xetVR.png)

```
=SUMIFS('GFEBS Pull'!Q:Q,'GFEBS Pull'!G:G,FMCOP!$C$20,'GFEBS Pull'!H:H,FMCOP!B23)
```

or:

```
=SUMIFS('GFEBS Pull'!Q:Q,'GFEBS Pull'!G:G,'FMCOP'!$C$20,'GFEBS Pull'!H:H,'FMCOP'!B23)
```

When I type ' around FMCOP sheet name, they disappear?  I've also tried to lock the columns on the 'GFEBS Pull' sheet with no luck.  Cell B23 is not locked because I'm going to copy the formula down to reference other cells. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need quotes around the sheet name when it's a single "word". For debugging purposes what result do you get using a COUNTIFS with the same criteria., i.e. `=COUNTIFS('GFEBS Pull'!G:G,FMCOP!$C$20,'GFEBS Pull'!H:H,FMCOP!B23)`

Comment: If you are using VBA cell.Formula = ... to put the formula in then **always** use chr(39) (single quotes or ticks) around a worksheet name. It does no harm if they are not required (single word worksheet name) but if they are not there and they are required (multi-word worksheet name) then you break your formula.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response!  I also got a return value of 0 for COUNTIFS?!  I'll attach that screenshot too.  As far as sheet name, I can remove it altogether and just leave $C$20 and B23 and when you double click, it highlights the correct cell.  I don't think the reference sheet is the actual problem, for some reason it just returns 0.

Comment: You likely have an unprintable character (space, vbLF and/or zero-length space come to mind) in the data columns. When you type the values into FMCOP!C20 and FMCOP!B23 you are not including the non-visible characters but when you click on the cells to test, you are. Put `=unicode(mid('GFEBS Pull'!G$5, row(1:1), 1))` into an unused cell and fill down. Do the same with `=unicode(mid('GFEBS Pull'!H$5, row(1:1), 1))`. All you should see is *72, 72, 67, #VALUE!* in successive rows. Anything other than that and you have rogue characters that are interferring with a match.

Comment: The cells in the data sheet are a vlookup from the upper table in the screenshot i just attached.  The cells i'm referencing (C20 and B23) are also a vlookup, but from the lower table in the same screenshot. Could it be that I'm not referencing the same table with the lookup?  I wouldn't think that would be the issue because in the formula builder screenshot you can see that the formula is returning the correct cell value based on the vlookup.

Comment: Actually, in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsIIk.png), you can **clearly** see that both FMCOP!C20 ansd FMCOP!B23 have prefacing spaces as in `" HHC"` and `" HHC"` will never match `"HHC"`. **Solution:** fix the data returned from *'the lower table in the same screenshot'*.

Comment: Ok I think you solved 1/2 the issue!  That extra space is automatically generated somehow when referencing the output of the dropdown I created.  The output cell is a number, then I created a reference to show the actual name of unit.  I'll continue to work with it and post if I can solve!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: ***Just reviewed the whole reference table and somehow there were spaces before AND after!  Thanks again for the help, now it all works like it should!

Comment: My advice: use a PivotTable. They slice, they dice, they aggregate, and they're idiot-proof when it comes to typos :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsIIk.png) you can clearly see that both FMCOP!C20 ansd FMCOP!B23 have prefacing spaces; e.g. `" HHC"`.

Since `" HHC"` will never match `"HHC"`, fix the data returned from *'the lower table in the same screenshot'*.

A Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish should do this. You could adjust the original formula like,

```
=SUMIFS('GFEBS Pull'!Q:Q, 'GFEBS Pull'!G:G, TRIM(FMCOP!$C$20), 'GFEBS Pull'!H:H, TRIM(FMCOP!B23))
```

I would caution against the latter 'bandaid' fix. Fix the original data; do not apply bandaids on-the-fly.

Comment: btw, my original character-by-character decode mentioned in comments above would have readily shown this as well. You likely have either ASCII character 160 (non-breaking space; typical when data is copied from a web page) or ASCII character 32 (regular space; easily removed with TextToColumns or TRIM).

Comment: the space in the "formula builder" screenshot sticks out like a sore thumb ... lol

Comment: @jsotola No sheet but I think we have all at some point been in a position where long hours in front of a computer screen breeds a special form of tunnel vision where we cannot see the forest for the trees,