# Does Excel if statement see the cells returned Value or the statement with in it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Two Columns returning a vlookup. How can I run an If statement on them? My return is always false. Here is what i have.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B172,Salaries!$B$2:$F$1000,5,FALSE),"")
```

This returns the Team of the Player, in this Case EDM. 
I have another column returning the Home Team (also EDM).

In a new column I run an `=if(Team column = Home column(Vlookup(player, Home Stats,3,false), (Vlookup(player,Road stats,3,false))` It will always return the Road stats because to me it see's each column as its statement not as EDM. It works in google sheets just fine, that's why I assume that would work in Excel. Thanks!

Comment: Formulas evaluate using referenced cell values, not any underlying formulas.  If your formula isn't working then one of its parts is returnng the wrong value.  Could be something as simple as an extra space appended to one of the values for example.  Edit - as in @jeeped's linked post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've omitted the literal references (i.e. cell addresses) of the player_cell, team_cell, home_cell, Home_Stats_range and Road_stats_range pretty vague but you could try this.

```
=vlookup(player_cell, if(team_cell=home_cell, Home_Stats_range, Road_stats_range), 3, false)
```

Comment: Still returning the Road Stats. Does It read the Cell as EDM or does it see it as  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Salaries!$B$2:$F$1000,5,FALSE),"") the Statement?

Comment: That expression works fine in Google sheets as well.

Comment: doing =N2=D2 return false. Both Are Vlookups that return EDM.

Comment: read the question, comments and answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243725/sumifs-returns-0-using-dynamic-criteria-with-criteria-range-and-sum-range-on-an/47244058#47244058)

Comment: If I type In ED in both its True, As soon as I type EDM in both it is False

Comment: read the question, comments and answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243725/sumifs-returns-0-using-dynamic-criteria-with-criteria-range-and-sum-range-on-an/47244058#47244058) again.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. Read it over twice and finally my found that my =left split had 1 too many characters in it! Thank you!